# Delete all records in table which have no reference in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-delete

I have a table which is called `Document`.

**Document**:

```
id int
docuid int
doc blob
```

Then I have two referencing tables

**AppRequiredDocuments**:

```
id int
appid int
docid int -> references document -> id
```

**AppDocuments**:

```
id int
appid int
docid int -> references document -> id
```

I have due to an very old migration orphaned items in the document table which have to references in the other tables. How can I delete only the documents in the document table which are not referenced in `AppDocuments` or `AppRequriedDocuments`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to find and delete those items:

```
delete from document d
where not exists (select 1 from AppRequiredDocuments a where a.docid = d.id);
and not exists (select 1 from AppDocuments a where a.docid = d.id);
```

Comment: forgot the aliases. Please try now?

Answer (score 8):

One approach uses a delete join:

```
DELETE d
FROM Document d
LEFT JOIN AppRequiredDocuments t1
  ON d.id = t1.docid
LEFT JOIN AppDocuments t2
  ON d.id = t2.docid
WHERE t1.docid IS NULL AND
      t2.docid IS NULL
```

The logic here is that if a given `Document` record is not referenced by *anything* in the two auxiliary tables, then in the result set of the join the `docid` columns for those two other tables should *both* be `NULL`.

Comment: You might need a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to get those rows that **don't exist** in the associated tables.... with an `INNER JOIN`; those rows aren't even going to be in the result set.....

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `union [all]` operator to generate a single column of references, and then check against it, e.g., with the `[not] exists` operator:

```
DELETE FROM Document d
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   AppRequiredDocuments ard
                   WHERE  ard.docid = d.id
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT *
                   FROM   AppDocuments ad
                   WHERE  ad.docid = d.id)
```