# Delete all records of a table which are not referenced in any other table; dozens of foreign tables; dynamic solution

Tags: sql-server, delete-row

I am looking for a solution to detect and delete all records of a table "UniqueKeys" which are not referenced anymore from records in any other table. As my question seems not clear, I have rephrased it.

**Challenge:**
If there is a table called "UniqueKeys" which consists of an ID and a uniqueIdentifier column and if there are dozens of tables which references the ID field of the "UniqueKeys" table - and now there are some records in the "UniqueKeys" table whose ID are not used in any of these other tables' references, I want to be able to detect and delete them with a SQL query without hard-code the joins to all of these other tables.

The found solutions so far included explicitly writing joins with each of the "other" tables which I want to avoid here.

Like this: [Other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41208123/delete-all-records-in-table-which-have-no-reference-in-another-table)

**The goal:** should be a generic solution so that at any time Devs can add additional foreign tables and this solution should continually be able (without modification) to detect any references to table "X" (and avoid the deletion of such affected records).

I know that I simply could programmatically (in the programming language of my choice) iterate through all given records of table "UniqueKeys" and use exception handling to simply continue when a given record cannot be deleted because of an active constraint.

This is what I am currently doing - and it yields the desired result - but imho this is a very ugly approach.

As I am no SQL expert, show me how to better re-phrase the above if that will help a better understanding of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Ummm, table schemas , sample data, and expected output would be nice. A little hint think Outer Join

Comment: The fact that you have "dozens of foreign tables" suggests a design flaw, or you're working with a data warehouse.

Comment: ".. anymore"? How do you intend to find table (and column) constraints that "no longer exist"? Do you have some way of knowing those that did but no longer exist? Or is that a misleading comment - you just want to delete rows if the table or any of its columns do not participate in a constraint? And what type of constraints? Any - like a check constraint (which seems irrelevant)?